# Content in PreferenceActivity goes over ToolBar

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-toolbar

I am trying to create **toolbar layout** and include it in specific Activities. However, I have already encountered a problem where my toolbar doesn't render correctly. All the content goes over the **toolbar**. Maybe that is the problem of ***PreferenceActivity***? Below you can see ***PreferenceActivity*** and ***activitySettings*** layout.

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.back_action_bar);
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(view -> onBackPressed());
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content,new MyPreferenceFragment()).commit();
    }

    public static class MyPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment
    {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_main);
        }
    }

}
```

*R.xml.pref_main* is just a preference page that I am using, which got displayed normally if there is no toolbar.
Here is my *activity_settings.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".Activity.SettingsActivity">
    <include android:id="@+id/back_action_bar" layout="@layout/toolbar"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/content1">
        <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

EDITED:

And here you can see my toolbarCode:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:id="@+id/settings_toolbar"
    app:navigationIcon="?attr/homeAsUpIndicator"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:title="Settings"/>
```

Comment: You don't actually need another `LinearLayout`. Try removing the second one plus `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` And that would be great to paste the `Toolbar` code too. Also, id of `ListView` deoesn't seems to be ok. Try `android:id="@+id/listView"`

Comment: I have edited my post, tried to delete what you said but it doesn't help. Content goes over the toolbar.

Comment: Here: `replace(android.R.id.content` it's  a reference to android resources. Shouldn't it be the content container of `Fragment` like `content1`?

Comment: I believe that id of listView is correct cuz otherwise my application crashes because an application doesn't recognize list where to put all preferences. 

I have also tried to do that, but if I put R.id.content1 nothing gets displayed...

Comment: I found a solution: 
Instead of LinearLayout in activitySettings I used FrameLayout and replaced android.R.id.content with content1 and after everything gets displayed perfectly. Thanks, ʍѳђઽ૯ท for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was actually pointing to `FrameLayout` instead of `LinearLayout`.

**Here:**

```
replace(android.R.id.content ...
```

Should be **the container of `Fragment`** because you are actually showing `Fragment` under the `Toolbar` and probably, `Fragment` couldn't be load properly with `LinearLayout`.